# Ionic 2 disable Infinite scroll spinner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an infinite scroll working perfectly, however, when I get to the end of my data, the spinner still spins. How do i stop the spinner?

As you can see, I am setting `hasMoreData` to `false`, but the spinner still spins.

Thanks

**html**

```
  <ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="hasMoreData" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**ts**

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll: InfiniteScroll) {
    this.firstResult += this.MAX_RESULTS;
    var promise: Promise<EmployeeModel[]>;
    promise = this.employeeService.getEmployeeRangeSearch(this.firstResult, this.MAX_RESULTS, this.latitude, this.longitude, this.maxDistance, this.miles, this.searchQuery);
    promise.then((employeeModels: EmployeeModel[]) => {
      for (var index = 0; index < employeeModels.length; index++) {
        this.employeeModels.push(employeeModels[index]);
      }
      if (employeeModels.length === 0) {
        infiniteScroll.enable(false);
        this.hasMoreData = false;
      } else {
        infiniteScroll.enable(true);
        this.hasMoreData = true;
      }
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hmm I've created [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5VBt1W?p=preview) with almost the exactly same code as the one posted and in the plunker it works properly. Could you please add a `debugger` in the `else { debugger; ... }` to see if that part of the code is being executed?

Comment: I don't think you need the `if (...) { }else { }` statement here. Just put `this.hasMoreData = employeeModels.length > 0;` `infiniteScroll.complete();` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Having said that pls check if you're getting into `then()` in the promise if you don't have the data.

Comment: Hi sebaferreras, thanks for your time. I run it with `console.log(..)`, and when it runs out of resultset, it executes as expected. It executes the following lines:         `infiniteScroll.enable(true);` & `this.hasMoreData = true;` & `infiniteScroll.complete();`. I am not sure why if `hasMoreData` is set to `true`, the spinner is still displaying?  Hi Jagannath, as you can see I am getting into the `.then` of the `Promise`, even when the result set is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need call function `enable(false)` when data is end.

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    //  Do your process
   // ..

  //if you no longer have data, usually in the asynchronous response of your call
  if(hasMoreData){
     infiniteScroll.enable(false);
  }
```

}

Just this already worked for me!